# Matrix operations in CUDA

Tags: c, cuda

What is the best way to organize matrix operations in CUDA (in terms of performance)?
For example, I want to calculate `C * C^(-1) * B^T + C`, `C` and `B` are matrices.

Should I write separate functions for  multiplication, transposition and so on or write one function for the whole expression?

Which way is the fastest?

Comment: Just a hint : For multiplication, there is a kind of algorithms called "Dynamic Programming", in the MIT Introduction to Algorithms, an example of these algorithms is how to choose the fastest order to multiply many matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer depends heavily on the size of your matrices.

If you can fit a matrix in shared memory, I would probably use a single block to compute that and have all inside a single kernel (probably bigger, where this computation is only a part of it). Hopefully, if you have more matrices, and you need to compute the above equation several times, you can do it in parallel, utilising all GPU computing power.

However, if your matrices are much bigger, you will want more blocks to compute that (check matrix multiplication example in CUDA manual). You need a guarantee that multiplication is finished by all blocks before you proceed with the next part of your equation, and if so, you will need a kernel call for each of your operations.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use the CUBLAS library. It's normally much daster and more reliable than everything you could write on your own. In addition it's API is similar to the BLAS library which is the standard library for numerical linear algebra.